# How to achieve this interface on interface builder?

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, interface-builder

i need to have a toolbar similar to this one :

[image]

I tried with a NSSegmentedControl with the NSSegmentStyleSmallSquare style but it doesn't look like the Xcode toolbar.

Also, i need to have a split view like in XCode with a very thin border (of one pixel ?) but the NSSplitView hasn't this style (even with NSSplitViewDividerStyleThin).

Is there a way to achieve this in Interface Builder or with another way (override drawRect ?) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. I mean you could probably use a few UIButtons with images and additional UIImageViews for the gradient background, but considering that this would be completely static (no easy way to rearrange the tabs, add a new tab, etc) I would really recommend writing your own tab control for that.